Visual studio 17: Publishing and installing a program has it inconsistently fail w/ "The request was aborted: The operation has timed out."
I inherited this project and am unfamiliar with publish / setup steps so please bare with me.
I am working on fixing an issue with people unable to download one of our applications hosted on our public server / website.
When I checked it out I got the following error.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://content.meriam.com/install/meriSuiteCGengBReale/meriSuiteCGeng.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading http://content.meriam.com/install/meriSuiteCGeng2/Application Files/meriSuiteCGeng_3_3_0_2/Resources/Fonts/Franklin Gothic Heavy Regular.ttf.deploy did not succeed.
        + The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [6/4/2024 3:20:06 PM] : Activation of http://content.meriam.com/install/meriSuiteCGengBReale/meriSuiteCGeng.application has started.
    * [6/4/2024 3:20:06 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [6/4/2024 3:20:06 PM] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [6/4/2024 3:20:06 PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [6/4/2024 3:20:08 PM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    * [6/4/2024 3:20:08 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [6/4/2024 3:20:33 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading http://content.meriam.com/install/meriSuiteCGeng2/Application Files/meriSuiteCGeng_3_3_0_2/Resources/Fonts/Franklin Gothic Heavy Regular.ttf.deploy did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.

What I changed to get it to partly work
When trying to publish I unchecked "connect using passive mode" and made the following changes to the code base.
I looked into the issue of the related font file and tried to include the "key" for spaces by changing it to...
            string fontFile = "unknown";
            try
            {
                fontFile = @"Resources\Fonts\Franklin%20Gothic%20Heavy%20Regular.ttf";
                // fontFile = @"Resources\Fonts\Franklin Gothic Heavy Regular.ttf";
                _boldFont = new OpenTypeFont(fontFile);
                if (_boldFont == null)
                    throw new Exception();
            }

And these changes seemed to work, for a day or two.
When I was checking it again (uninstall app, restart, reinstall)
I wound up with the same error again.
I went to the hosted app via the url path http://content.meriam.com/install/ and went to my font file and was unable to download it. When I FTPed into it with filezilla I was able to download the file just fine.
I came into work this morning and the application was able to be installed with no issue and the font file could be downloaded from the hosted site.
Any idea what is going on?
I have also checked out other timeout issues on this forum and looked up issues related to click once, but I think it might be something with my computer / server cache as the install success depends on the day it is used.

By accessing your URL in browser , i  am able to download Franklin Gothic Book Regular.ttf.deploy and Franklin Gothic Demi Regular.ttf.deploy  files except Franklin Gothic Heavy Regular.ttf.deploy file in your font folder. Are you publishing these three deploy files in the same way? Any different settings?

Can you check the log file  when the font file can be downloaded properly ？From the error log you provided,  it seems spaces in the URL are not translated.

Thanks for the reply. How do I find where that log file is? I searched AppData/Local/Temp and couldn't find any file that contains 'gothic'.
Also, I am able to download Franklin Gothic Demi Regular.tff.deploy directly from the site.
I did update just the text of that font file in my code since it's the one where it errored on, the other fonts have spaces in the URL instead of '%20' (see above). That allowed me to install it correctly, although it could of just been a coincidence.

How did you see these error information above when the .ttf.deploy file downloaded failed?

When the installation fails it gives me a log file. It does not tell me the location of the failed file, nor does it give me one when it succeeds.
